# Split EDI string on ' in c#

Tags: c#, split

I'm trying to split an EDI string on char ' as the string to split looks like this:

```
UNA:+.? 'UNB+UNOC:3+5790001667962:14+5790000013289:14+170314:1658+53387++KUNDEMIN5'
```

and i would like a list containing

```
"UNA:+.?", "UNB+UNOC:3+5790001667962:14+5790000013289:14+170314:1658+53387++KUNDEMIN5" etc.
```

I've tried to use escape char but it doesn't seem to work:

```
var orderElements = order.Split('\'').ToList();
```

where order contains the string to split.

Any great ideas?

Comment: Here it works: https://ideone.com/qO7sRl

Comment: `Split('\'');` should work. What is the problem with that code?

Comment: [Works for me](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Widget/9ECO0k), are you sure that apostrophe isn't a prime, actue, grave or anything similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your input and expected output there is a space that has gone missing. If you really want to remove that space you could use LINQs `Select` extension method:

```
var orderElements = order.Split('\'').Select(s => s.Trim()).ToList();
```

Also the string ends in an `'` so you might want to remove empty entries like:

```
.Split(new char[] { '\'' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```